# Rotations in complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So i was doing some experiments in my free time, tried think of a free particle in  $\Bbb C$, which lead me to think of defining functions in $\Bbb C$ the non standard way, instead of thinking of functions $\mathscr{F}:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, we could consider only functions of the form $$f_{\Bbb R}:\Bbb R\to\cal J$$ where ${\cal J}=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(x)=0\}=\{x\in\mathbb C, b\in\mathbb R:x=ib\}$,  so it takes a real $x$ into a real valued function I'll call $f(x)$ and outputs $if(x)$, so the function $f_{\Bbb R}:x\mapsto if(x)$

Similarly we could consider $$g_{\Bbb C}:\mathcal J\to\Bbb R$$ where it takes an imaginary $x$, transform it into a real number $ix$ and then compose it with a real valued function $g$, giving $g(ix)$, so $g_{\Bbb C}:x\mapsto g(ix)$

it is easy to see that if $f=g$, then $f_{\Bbb  C}$ is simply a rotation of $f_{\Bbb R}$ by $90^°$ in the complex plane.

so i tried to write $f_{\Bbb R}$ in terms of $f_{\Bbb C}$, the non obvious way, i knew already that rotations can be represented as matrices, and that there was a specific matrix for that known as the rotation matrix $$R_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$ but how can one apply it in the case of the complex plane? would that be useful?

What if I took $f_{\mathbb{R}}$ and rotated it by an angle other than $90^°$ like $45^°$?

Comment: What is *"the non standard way"* of defining functions in $\Bbb{C}$? And do your $f_{\Bbb{R}}$ and $f_{\Bbb{C}}$ depend on some function $f:\ \Bbb{C}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}$? If so, what happens if $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @Servaes i explained that in the post, "lead me to think of defining functions in $\Bbb C$ the non standard way, **instead of thinking of functions $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, we could consider only functions of the form** $$f_{\Bbb R}:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$$" No, the function doesn't depend on $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, rather throughout the  paragraphs  $f$ is assumed to be real valued,  ( I edited the post to remove that confusion, now $\mathscr{F}$ is a complex valued function, and $f$ is a real valued one)

Comment: Then what if $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in\Bbb{R}$? Then $f_{\Bbb{R}}(x)=if(x)=i\cdot0=0$, but $0\notin\Bbb{C}\backslash\Bbb{R}$. It means that if you want $f_{\Bbb{R}}$ to be continuous, then $f$ should be everywhere positive, or everywhere negative, to begin with.

Comment: Moreover, for the other direction $g_{\Bbb{C}}:\ \Bbb{C}\backslash\Bbb{R}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}$, multiplying some arbitrary $x\in\Bbb{C}\backslash\Bbb{R}$ by $i$ does not yield a real number in general.

Comment: @Servaes oh right, forgot that, I should have instead considered the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}\cup\{0\}$ because of the fact that $i0=0$

Comment: @Servaes yes, another mistake, it should have been the set $\cal J$ such that ${\cal J}=\{x\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(x)=0\}$, that is those numbers of the form $ib$

Comment: So now you're only considering functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $i\Bbb{R}$ and back? These are precisely all real functions, except that you write $i$ in front of them sometimes. I don't see the point...

Comment: @Servaes yes, was just exploring that possibility, so how can i apply the rotation matrix there to write those functions in terms of each other? What if i took $f_{\Bbb R}$ and I rotated it by $45^°$? also one can try to define some sort of structure on those functions and see if it leads somewhere...,

Comment: The structure is very simple; it is the same as that of the set of all real functions. The only difference is that you compose them all with some fixed map (in this case some rotation).

Comment: @Servaes i mean what if we defined $f_{\Bbb R}\oplus g_{\Bbb C}$ or $f_{\Bbb R}\otimes g_{\Bbb C}$, that wouldn't behave as normal real functions because they don't have the same domain! (except at $0$)